# K&R: subtracting one pointer from another

Tags: c, c-strings, strcmp, function-definition, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am reading K&R and on 5.5 there is code he included for strcmp:

```
/* strcmp: return <0 if s<t, 0 if s==t, >0 if s>t */
int strcmp(char *s, char *t)
{
    for(; *s == *t; s++, t++)
         if (*s == '\0');
             return 0;
    return *s - *t;
}
```

previously it stated in the book that

> the valid pointer operations are assignment of pointers of the same type, adding or subtracting a pointer and an integer, subtracting or comparing two pointers to members of the same array, and assigning or comparing to zero. **All other pointer arithmetic is illegal.**

the line `return *s - *t;` is legal because he is subtracting the content of two pointers pointing to two different character arrays but if he did `s - t` this would be illegal as he is trying to take the difference of the address held by the two pointers which is undefined?

Comment: *"but if he did `s - t` this would be illegal"* - `s - t` is legit so long as both pointers refer to the same array, including the one-past address.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `*s` and `*t` are just ordinary integers, you can do any arithmetic with them.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's obviously just a typo when copying

Comment: `*s - *t` isn't "pointer arithmetic". It is arithmetic on the integer values being pointed to.

Comment: "is legit so long as both pointers refer to the same array," in this case, receiving them as parameters, it is not generally guaranteed that they will be.

Comment: Why ask about `s - t` in code that doesn't do `s - t` ? And further ... even if `s - t` was legal it would make no sense for `strcmp`

Comment: I am voting to close this question as OP asks about non existent problem

Comment: @4386427 it qualifies for deletion.

Comment: What's so terrible about this question that it should be closed? OP clearly did some research, provided some context, and asked about a "what if" scenario to lay a base for further clarification. I find it particularly amusing that one user who voted to close also provided an answer ...

Comment: Why so grumpy? OP submitted a clear question, some research and you will find plenty of questions about “non existent problems”.

Answer (score 2):

> the line `return *s - *t;` is legal because he is subtracting the content of two pointers pointing to two different character arrays

It doesn't matter what arrays they're pointing to. `*s` and `*t` are both `char` values, so this is just subtracting numbers.

> but if he did `s - t` this would be illegal as he is trying to take the difference of the address held by the two pointers which is undefined?

This is essentially correct. While it's possible that the pointers point into the same array (you can write (`strcmp(s1, s1+1)`), there's no way to know that when writing `strcmp()`. So you normally must assume they point to different arrays, and the subtraction is invalid.

The only type of operation you can do between pointers that may be to different arrays is comparing them with `==` or `!=`.

Comment: `The only potential problem is if char is signed, and the subtraction results in a value outside the valid range of char`  No - it is promoted to `int`. No danger

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I removed that.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you made a typo

```
    if (*s == '\0'); // <===
        return 0;
```

You shall remove the semicolon.

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
> the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
> object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
> array elements.

Thus this expression `s - t` invokes undefined behavior provided that the pointers do not point to elements of the same array.  (To compare a string and its substring does not make a sense because they always will be unequal)

Pay attention to that the function definition is incorrect. The function should be declared and defined the following way

```
int strcmp( const char *s, const char *t)
{
    while ( *s && *s == *t )
    {
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }

    return ( unsigned char )*s - ( unsigned char )*t;
}
```

Pay attention to the casting to the type `unsigned char` in the return statement.

Consider the demonstrative program (I renamed your function to distinguish its call from a call of the standard C function strcmp). The type `char` behaves as the type `signed char` in the used compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int kr_strcmp(char *s, char *t)
{
    for(; *s == *t; s++, t++)
         if (*s == '\0')
             return 0;
    return *s - *t;
}

int kr_strcmp_updated( const char *s, const char *t)
{
    while ( *s && *s == *t )
    {
        ++s;
        ++t;
    }

    return ( unsigned char )*s - ( unsigned char )*t;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[] = { 127, '\0' };
    char s2[] = { -128, '\0' };
    
    printf( "kr_strcmp: %d\n", kr_strcmp( s1, s2 ) );   
    printf( "kr_strcmp_updated: %d\n", kr_strcmp_updated( s1, s2 ) );   
    printf( "strcmp: %d\n", strcmp( s1, s2 ) ); 

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
kr_strcmp: 255
kr_strcmp_updated: -1
strcmp: -1
```

As you can see the function shown by you yields a positive value instead of a negative value as the standard string function `strcmp` does.

Answer (score 0):

You are not substracting pointers in your example only `char` (integer) objects referenced by pointers.